# Akka Persistence Cassandra: timestamp != offset. Or how to process events only once?

Tags: cassandra, akka, akka-persistence

I am currently building an event sourced application with Akka Persistence and the Cassandra Journal Plugin.
I have some views, which need to capture events of multiple persistence ids, therefore I am using the eventsByTag queries to update (e.g.) my mongodb views.

If I restart my application, the query gets replayed, so I need to somehow store the state of the views, so it does not replay events, which have already been processed.

At first I planned on using the offset of the last processed event, since the Cassandra Plugin uses TimeUUID internally and it should be unique. The problem here is, that Akka Journal only supports Long values as offset so the TimeUUID gets converted back to a normal timestamp.

So e.g.:

2d2504b1-31f8-11e6-af83-9f34c8060f40
and
2d2504b2-31f8-11e6-af83-9f34c8060f40

both result in the same offset, which makes it useless for me in terms of determining the last processed event, if I have multiple events within the same ms.

Does anyone have an idea on how to approach this in a better way?

EDIT

---

The `CassandraReadJournal` provides an overloaded version of the getEventsByTag stream, which returns UUIDEventEnvelopes. This contains the offset as UUID and not Long.

Comment: Can you find a way to make your updates idempotent?  If not, can you leverage document versioning to reject a change that has already been applied, trying to line up the document version with the sequence number relating to the events for that persistenceId?

Comment: I will think about the idempotency, but my first guess would be that it is not feasible in my case. As for the versioning, some views aggregate events of multiple persistence ids, so I can't use it as version (single persistenceId views wouldn't be a problem).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `CassandraReadJournal` provides an overloaded version of the `getEventsByTag` stream, which returns `UUIDEventEnvelopes`. This contains the offset as `UUID` and not `Long` and is therefore unique.

Comment: the "UUID"s returned aren't real UUID but rather unix timestamp stuffed into a UUID and thus _not_ unique. See https://github.com/tfredrich/cassandra-java-driver/blob/master/driver-core/src/main/java/com/datastax/driver/core/utils/UUIDs.java#L160